# Cython: understanding what the html annotation file has to say?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

After compiling the following Cython code, I get the html file that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef my_function(np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] array_a,
                  np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] array_b,
                  int n_rows,
                  int n_columns):

    array_a[0:-1:n_columns] = 0
    array_a[n_columns - 1:n_rows * n_columns:n_columns] = 0
    array_a[0:n_columns] = 0
    array_a[n_columns* (n_rows - 1):n_rows * n_columns] = 0
    array_b[array_a == 3] = 0

    return array_a, array_b
```

[image]

My question is that why those operations of my function are still yellow? Does this mean that the code is still not as fast as it could be using Cython?

Comment: Did you expand any of those lines with the `+`?  Useful documentation; http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types

Comment: Yes I did. I understand that they are translated C code but can't figure out why they are still yellow after all the types are declared.

Comment: It's not just a matter of declaring.  Even if it knows that `array_a` is a `ndarray`, it still has to use `numpy` calls (at the C level) to perform that indexing.  Look at the `typed memoryview` page to get some ideas on how you can operate on the arrays as 'native' cython objects.

Comment: Ok, I now see what you mean. I'm reading about `memoryview`, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @hpaulj How about creating a memory view of `array_a` inside the function and do the operations on them: `cdef double [:] v_a = array_a`
    operations:     
    `v_a[0:-1:n_columns] = 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already know, yellow lines mean that some interactions with python happen, i.e. python functionality and not raw c-functionality is used, and you can look into the produced code to see, what happens and if it can/should be fixed/avoided.

Not every interaction with python means a (measurable) slowdown.

Let's take a look at this simplified function:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
def use_slices(np.ndarray[np.double_t] a):
    a[0:len(a)]=0.0
```

When we look into the produced code we see (I kept only the important parts):

```
  __pyx_t_1 = PyObject_Length(((PyObject *)__pyx_v_a)); 
  __pyx_t_2 = PyInt_FromSsize_t(__pyx_t_1); 
  __pyx_t_3 = PySlice_New(__pyx_int_0, __pyx_t_2, Py_None); 
  PyObject_SetItem(((PyObject *)__pyx_v_a)
```

So basically we get a new slice (which is a numpy-array) and then use numpy's functionality (`PyObject_SetItem`) to set all elements to `0.0`, which is C-code under the hood.

Let's take a look at version with hand-written for loop:

```
cimport numpy as np
def use_for(np.ndarray[np.double_t] a):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i]=0.0
```

It still uses `PyObject_Length` (because of `length`) and bound-checking, but otherwise it is C-code. When we compare times:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.ones((500,))
>>> %timeit use_slices(a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.85 µs per loop
>>> %timeit use_for(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 µs per loop

>>> b=np.ones((250000,))
>>> %timeit use_slices(b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 µs per loop
>>> %timeit use_for(b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 364 µs per loop
```

You can see the additional overhead of creating a slice for small sizes, but the additional checks in the for-version means it has more overhead in the long run.

Let's disable these checks:

```
%%cython
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def use_for_no_checks(np.ndarray[np.double_t] a):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i]=0.0
```

In the produced html we can see, that  `a[i]` gets as simple as it gets:

```
 __pyx_t_3 = __pyx_v_i;
    *__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(__pyx_t_5numpy_double_t *, __pyx_pybuffernd_a.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf, __pyx_t_3, __pyx_pybuffernd_a.diminfo[0].strides) = 0.0;
  }
```

`__Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(type, buf, i0, s0)` is define for `(type)((char*)buf + i0 * s0)`.
And now:

```
>>> %timeit use_for_no_checks(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 µs per loop
>>> %timeit use_for_no_checks(b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 246 µs per loop
```

We can improve it further by releasing gil in the for-loop:

```
%%cython
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def use_for_no_checks_no_gil(np.ndarray[np.double_t] a):
    cdef int i
    cdef int n=len(a)
    with nogil:
      for i in range(n):
        a[i]=0.0
```

and now:

```
>>> %timeit use_for_no_checks_no_gil(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 µs per loop
>>> %timeit use_for_no_checks_no_gil(b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop
```

So it is somewhat faster, but still you cannot beat numpy for larger arrays.

In my opinion, there are two things to take from it:

1. Cython will not transform slices to an access through a for-loop and thus Python-functionality must be used.
2. There is small overhead, but it is only calling the numpy-functionality the most of work is done in numpy-code, and this cannot be speed up through Cython.

---

One last try using `memset` function:

```
%%cython
from libc.string cimport memset
cimport numpy as np
def use_memset(np.ndarray[np.double_t] a):
    memset(&a[0], 0, len(a)*sizeof(np.double_t))
```

We get:

```
>>> %timeit use_memset(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 821 ns per loop
>>> %timeit use_memset(b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop
```

It is also as fast as the numpy-code for large arrays.

---

As DavidW suggested, one could try to use memory-views:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
def use_slices_memview(double[::1] a):
    a[0:len(a)]=0.0
```

leads to a slightly faster code for small arrays but similar fast code fr large arrays (compared to numpy-slices):

```
>>> %timeit use_slices_memview(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 µs per loop

>>> %timeit use_slices_memview(b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 µs per loop
```

That means, that the memory-view slices have less overhead than the numpy-slices. Here is the produced code:

```
 __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_MemoryView_Len(__pyx_v_a); 
  __pyx_t_2.data = __pyx_v_a.data;
  __pyx_t_2.memview = __pyx_v_a.memview;
  __PYX_INC_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_t_2, 0);
  __pyx_t_3 = -1;
  if (unlikely(__pyx_memoryview_slice_memviewslice(
    &__pyx_t_2,
    __pyx_v_a.shape[0], __pyx_v_a.strides[0], __pyx_v_a.suboffsets[0],
    0,
    0,
    &__pyx_t_3,
    0,
    __pyx_t_1,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    0,
    1) < 0))
{
    __PYX_ERR(0, 27, __pyx_L1_error)
}

{
      double __pyx_temp_scalar = 0.0;
      {
          Py_ssize_t __pyx_temp_extent = __pyx_t_2.shape[0];
          Py_ssize_t __pyx_temp_idx;
          double *__pyx_temp_pointer = (double *) __pyx_t_2.data;
          for (__pyx_temp_idx = 0; __pyx_temp_idx < __pyx_temp_extent; __pyx_temp_idx++) {
            *((double *) __pyx_temp_pointer) = __pyx_temp_scalar;
            __pyx_temp_pointer += 1;
          }
      }
  }
  __PYX_XDEC_MEMVIEW(&__pyx_t_2, 1);
  __pyx_t_2.memview = NULL;
  __pyx_t_2.data = NULL;
```

I think the most important part: this code doesn't create an additional temporary object - it reuses the existing memory view for the slice.

My compiler produces (at least for my machine) a slightly faster code if memory views are used. Not sure whether it is worth an investigation. At the first sight the difference in every iteration step is:

```
# created code for memview-slices:
*((double *) __pyx_temp_pointer) = __pyx_temp_scalar;
 __pyx_temp_pointer += 1;

#created code for memview-for-loop:
 __pyx_v_i = __pyx_t_3;
 __pyx_t_4 = __pyx_v_i;
 *((double *) ( /* dim=0 */ ((char *) (((double *) data) + __pyx_t_4)) )) = 0.0;
```

I would expect different compilers handle this code differently well. But clearly, the first version is easier to get optimized.

---

As Behzad Jamali pointed out, there is difference between `double[:] a` and `double[::1] a`. The second version using slices is about 20% faster on my machine. The difference is, that during the compile time it is know for the `double[::1]` version, that the memory-accesses will be consecutive and this can be used for optimization. In the version with `double[:]` we don't know anything about stride until the runtime.

Comment: As far as I understood if we don't have yellow lines we can use `nogil`. Is this also an important consideration?

Comment: @BehzadJamali Thanks, I have forgotten to release gil, so this would speed-up the for-version somewhat (see my edit). However, it still cannot beat numpy. If I'm not mistaken numpy releases gil for this kind of operations.

Comment: It might be worth quickly looking at memoryview slices too. I doubt they'd be any different in speed but it's possible that they might be naturally gil-free. (That said, I doubt it's as important to release the gil as OP things)

Comment: @DavidW I took a look at memory view slices and added some details to the answer. Surprisingly, they have less overhead than the numpy-slices and produce a slightly different c-code which can be optimized better at least with my compiler.

Comment: Why you used double[: : 1] a in the memoryview part. Why not double[:] a?

Comment: @BehzadJamali Basically I give the information that the compiler, that the data is continuous in the memory. That helps compiler to optimize code, thus `double[::1]` can be sometimes faster (but never slower). Actually for this example `double[::1]` is somewhat faster.

Comment: Can I also benefit from memory views for `array_b[array_a == 3] = 0`?

Comment: @BehzadJamali I don’t know. You will have to measure it, to be certain. But I would not dwell too long on it, because the differences are not very big, and use whatever is easier to maintain.